# beamer miniframe alignment

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I added a mainframe to my beamer slides.

I just have two Sections in my slides. Right now, the content in the mainframe seems to be fully justified, so there's a big horizontal space in between "First Section" and "Second Section" (see screenshot below). Can I do "left-align" instead, so "Second Section" will appear much closer to "First Section"?

[image]

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
    \usetheme{default}
    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
    ...
\begin{document}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the navigation like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}

\makeatletter
\def\insertnavigation#1{%
  \vbox{{%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
    \beamer@xpos=0\relax%
    \beamer@ypos=1\relax%
    \beamer@ypos@offset=0\relax%
    \hbox to #1{\hskip.3cm\setbox\beamer@sectionbox=\hbox{\kern1sp}%
      \ht\beamer@sectionbox=1.875ex%
      \dp\beamer@sectionbox=0.75ex%
        \hskip-1.875ex plus-1fill%
        \global\beamer@section@min@dim\z@
        \dohead%
        \beamer@section@set@min@width
      \box\beamer@sectionbox\hfil\hskip.3cm\hskip0pt plus1filll}%
  }}} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{title} 
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\section{title} 
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked!

Comment: @jet You're welcome!